# How to prove a lock held and delayed in a tight loop may not be acquired by a waiting thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

... but had a weird result.

I was reviewing code on a retry thread. The idea is simple: look up the cache, if it's not in cache, delay and retry again. 
Another thread is obviously writing to same cache and using the same lock object.

I spotted what I thought was a potential bug where there was a Task.Delay(1).Wait() inside the lock of the retry thread and my "argument"/theory was that although the retry loop releases the lock, it could still acquire the lock before the writing thread could.

So I decided to see if I could quickly reproduce the code (rather badly):

```
namespace TaskDelay
{
    class Program
    {
        static Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        static  BlockingCollection<int> bc = new BlockingCollection<int>();
        static  ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        static  ManualResetEvent nresetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Run();

            Console.Read();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            var t = new Thread(RetryThread);
            t.Start();
            var v = new Thread(TryAdd);
            v.Start();
            bc.Add(20);
            bc.Add(21);
            resetEvent.Set();

        }

        public void RetryThread()
        {
            resetEvent.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Starting RetryLoop");
            bool done = false;
            nresetEvent.Set();
            while (!done)
            {
                done = RetryLoop(21);
            }

        }
        public bool RetryLoop(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"In Retry loop {x}");

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                lock (dict)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine($"Entering Retry loop {x}. Count {i+1}");
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(x))
                    {
                        Task.Delay(1).Wait();//Change to Thread.Sleep(1) 
                        continue;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"eXITING Retry loop {x}");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        void TryAdd()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting TryAdd");
            nresetEvent.WaitOne();

            for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1500)
                    break;
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Exited loop");
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            lock (dict)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Entered lock try add");
                dict[21] = "hello";
                Console.WriteLine("Exit lock try add");
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

I tried 3 test cases in the RetryLoop with these outcomes:

1. Use Task.Delay(1).Wait() in lock.
2. Use Thread.Sleep(1) in lock
3. No delay in lock

In case 1: the writing thread acquires the lock faster. Instantly, once the writing thread exits its simple counter loop.

[image: Test case 1]

In cases 2 and 3: it somewhat proves the theory that the writing thread may not acquire the lock for sometime. In other words, it took a lot longer.

[image: Test case 2]

Notice the gap in two images.. My question is why is case 1 significantly faster? Maybe I was wrong then...

I understand that this code is not deterministic and may even be flawed. Open to alternatives.

Comment: 1 is probably faster because there is no context switching...there is no other thread.

Comment: @rory.ap RetryThread is started on a different thread and calls RetryLoop.

Comment: I'd argue that if `Task.Delay(1).Wait()` is part of the production code it's a bug *in and of itself*, because needing to throw in an explicit delay of this kind (instead of leaving this to lower-level lock primitives) is a sure sign of code that doesn't really know what it's doing. See also: `Monitor.Wait`, `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, `ConcurrentDictionary`, `ConcurrentQueue`, things like Stephen Cleary's `AsyncMonitor`, etc. Rewriting the code so it's obviously correct (and lacking magic constants like `5`) would obviate the need to "prove" it's definitely (not) buggy.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Production code is definitely not using magic constants. It's better written :p And the bug has been fixed. But the question still remains... why there is a different behavior with Task.Delay?

Comment: Number of cores, phase of the moon, the fact that `Task.Delay(1).Wait()` and `Thread.Sleep(1)` don't use the same mechanism for delaying... I'll freely admit that I'm not the kind of expert on multithreading that could unravel this mystery, and I actually strongly prefer keeping it that way so I'm not tempted to write code I can't debug. Note that `lock` also uses its own combination of spin waiting and devolving to waiting on an event if it takes too long, so the situation as a whole can become quite complicated. Waiting "longer" at one point can mean code can run "faster".

Comment: My crystal ball says that you use the Chrome browser.  Be careful, it messes with the OS too much to make Sleep(1) and Delay(1) act deterministically.  The difference you see is caused by Thread.Sleep being much better at resuming the thread.  Task.Delay has overhead, it needs a worker thread inside the CLR and a threadpool thread to run before it can resume.  So with Thread.Sleep it can loop more often.  Use Stopwatch to measure elapsed time, what you actually want to know.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the suggestion. I will try a more isolated environment.